# Cgit master branch not available

Tags: git, gitolite, cgit

Problem: 'master' branch is missing in the repo refs list. Using cgit v0.9.0.3 + gitolite.

cgitrc contents:

```
virtual-root=/cgit/
enable-index-links=1
enable-log-filecount=1
enable-log-linecount=1
snapshots=tar.gz tar.bz zip

repo.group=myrepo
repo.url=myrepo
repo.path=/appdata/git/repositories/myrepo.git
repo.desc=main repo
repo.owner=my@domain.com
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!